# Trigger and Function Code

Tags: mysql, sql, function, triggers

I am making a SQL database for a shop and I have a little problem in functions and triggers, and I really hope someone here can help me out!

What I need is to create a function [GetDiscount] to get the DISCOUNT_RATE for a particular PROD_CAT from the Discount Table. Along with setting an exception when DISCOUNT_RATE is not found for particular PROD_CAT to create a Trigger [TrgDisAmount] to read PROD_NAME and Price from Product Table and to calculate the DISCOUNT and AMOUNT of SALES Table for every new row with Serial and PCODE, but for the TRIGGER I need to enter the values of PCODE and Serial only, rest should be entered automatically using the trigger.

I can't actually attach a pic of tables due to my low reputation and points so if anyone is willing to help. We can perhaps e-mail?

Comment: You should show us your table definition, the code you tried so far and how this value has to be calculated. However, if i understood it well, I recomend you to create a stored procedure to update this information. After that, create a "AFTER INSERT" trigger which call this procedure.  You could use it in the function too. if you can't get the discount_rate, you can call the store procedure inside the function and repeat the before select.

Comment: respected sir. i have used very basic commands to create the table without any special attributes. however. i would like to redirect you to [link] (http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/function-and-trigger-code-t15935/#post36813) if you would like to see table images. inserting data and creating table steps are done. and i would prefer using trigger and functions so please help me out here

Comment: CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
PCODE VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY,
PROD_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PROD_CAT VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PRICE NUMBER(9,3));


CREATE TABLE DISCOUNT
PROD_CAT VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
DISCOUNT_RATE NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE SALES
SLNO NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
PCODE VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
PROD_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRICE NUMBER(9,3),
DISCOUNT NUMBER(9,3),
AMOUNT NUMBER(9,3));
);